# Injecting dependency into base class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

I have the following BaseClass:

```
public class BaseRepositorio : IDisposable
{
    protected IDbConnection postgresql;

    public BaseRepositorio(IDbConnection postgresql)
    {
        this.postgresql = postgresql;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
}
```

What is the proper way to inject the dependency into the BaseClass?

```
public class RepositorioEmpresa : BaseRepositorio?!?!, IRepositorio<Empresa>
{
}
```

Comment: If you tried compiling your code the compiler would tell you that you need to add a constructor to your derived class.

Comment: For whatever reason, that seems to be more easy for you than for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject it in the derived and use base constructor

```
public class RepositorioEmpresa : BaseRepositorio, IRepositorio<Empresa>
{
    public RepositorioEmpresa(IDbConnection connection): base(connection)
    {
    }
}
```